# Joining sql statements

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have this statement:

```
SELECT board.*, numlikes 
FROM board
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
              pins.board_id, COUNT(source_user_id) AS numlikes
           FROM likes 
           INNER JOIN pins ON pins.id = likes.pin_id 
           GROUP BY pins.board_id) likes ON board.id = likes.board_id
WHERE who_can_tag = '' 
ORDER BY numlikes DESC LIMIT 10
```

But I need to also join these other two statements to it:

```
SELECT COUNT(owner_user_id) 
FROM repin 
INNER JOIN pins ON pins.id = repin.from_pin_id 
WHERE pins.board_id = '$id'
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(is_following_board_id) 
FROM follow 
WHERE is_following_board_id = '$id'
```

I managed to get the first one joined but I'm having trouble with the others - thinking it might get too long.

Is there a quicker way to execute?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, start with the smallest result set, and then start joining to the next smallest table.

You don't want the database to do full table joins on a bunch of big tables, and then at the end have a where clause that removes 99% of the rows the database just created.

In Oracle, I do a:

```
SELECT *
  FROM big_table bt
  JOIN DUAL ON bt.best_filter_column='the_value'
--now there are only a few rows
  JOIN other_table_1 ...
  LEFT JOIN outer_join_tables ...
```

Include all OUTER JOINS last, since they don't drop any rows, so hopefully you've already filtered out a lot of rows.